# Подскажите аналог nameof, чтобы отобразить не только атрибут, но и его вхождения

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В своем приложении я часто использую nameof оператор для работы с базой данных через ORM. К примеру, использую nameof(Employee.Id) и вывожу Id соответственно (конечно, мы можем прописывать атрибут через кавычки, но не всегда удается таким образом отследить изменения объекта).

Но появилась необходимость в том, чтобы отобразить не только атрибут, но и вхождения, к примеру, какой-нибудь_оператор(Employee.Job.Country.Id) и появился Job.Country.Id, можете подсказать как это сделать?

Условно, я хочу чтобы второй nameof(Test.Count.Id) вернул мне Count.Id

```
var esqTest = new EntitySchemaQuery(userConnection.EntitySchemaManager, nameof(Test));
esqTest.AddAllSchemaColumns();

esqTest.Filters.Add(esqTest.CreateFilterWithParameters(FilterComparisonType.Equal, nameof(Test), selectedRow));
esqTest.Filters.Add(esqTest.CreateFilterWithParameters(FilterComparisonType.Equal, nameof(Test.Count.Id), 2));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оператор `nameof()` возвращает обычную строку типа `string`. Следовательно и все строковые операции к нему применимы.

Comment: @aepot я пытался самостоятельно создать какой-нибудь метод, чтобы распарсить путь (getpath(Employee.Job.Country.Id)), но компилятор запрещает делать такие записи, можно конечно сделать типо nameof(Employee) + nameof(Employee.Country) и т. д., но это долго( подумал, что есть более просто способ.

Comment: Добавьте весь не рабочий код в вопрос, и объясните, как он работает, и как должен. Приведите примеры данных, конкретные, придумайте тестовый пример, простой, можно на базе отдельного пустого проекта. А пока не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться. `nameof` - это строка-константа, примочка компилятора, никаких динамических операций с этим у вас не получится.

Comment: @aepot примерно такой пример

Comment: [Вставьте код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @aepot добавил текст

Answer (score 2):

хз то или не то, но вот есть такой фокус.

Например, у нас класс

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
}
```

Напишем простой Extension метод

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static string PropsPath<T, K>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, K>> exp)
    {
        return exp.Body.ToString();
    }       
}
```

Как можно вызвать

```
Foo myObject = new Foo();;
var ret = myObject.PropsPath(x=>x.Id);
Console.WriteLine(ret);
```

на выходе будет

```
x.Id
```

Имейте ввиду, что этот код не сильно эффективный, так что я бы не стал в каких то критических по производительности местах его использовать.